# Llenar mi select con php y mysql

Tags: php, html

```
<div id= "ID">
    <label> Selecciona ID: <select name="">

    <?php
    include 'conectar.php';
    $insertarDatos="SELECT ID from alumno";
   
    $ejecutarInsertar=mysqli_query($enlace,$insertarDatos) or die (mysqli_error($conectar));

    ?>
    <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opciones['ID']?>"></option>
    <?php 
    ?>
    </select>
    </label>
```

este es mi código de php.

y en interfaz solo sale: Selecciona ID.
y al seleccionarlo debe de mostrarme los datos guardados en la base de datos.

Comment: Te falta hacer algún *fetch*.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: que error te sale???...

Comment: Hola no es el hecho que $ejecutar no existe, en su lugar es $ejecutarInsertar. más bien es algho asi while ($opciones= mysqli_fetch_row($ejecutarInsertar)) {
    echo "<option value="$opciones['ID']"></option>";
}
Ya te tocaria a ti checar porque escapas muchas veces de PHP a HTML, otra sugerencia es que uses bien tus identificadores. los llamas $ejecutarInsertar cuando estás haciendo un SELECT, lo que es una SELECCIÖN, no una INSERCION

Comment: @John aquí se enseña o se menciona que hacer para ayudar. Así que no andes con esos aires, no es de afuerzas ayudar en esta plataforma, saludos.